# Spring Boot 1.4 testing with Security enabled?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm wondering how I should go about authenticating a user for my tests? As it stands now all tests I will write will fail because the endpoints require authorization.

Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = PostController.class)
public class PostControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private PostService postService;

    @Test
    public void testHome() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("posts"));
    }


}
```

One solution I found is to disable it by setting secure to false in @WebMvcTest. But that's not what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Spring Security provides a `@WithMockUser` annotation that can be used to indicate that a [test should be run as a particular user](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser):

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "test", password = "test", roles = "USER")
public void withMockUser() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using basic authentication, you could send the required `Authorization` header:

```
@Test
public void basicAuth() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
            .perform(get("/").header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                    "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString("user:secret".getBytes())))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Spring Security even has built-in support for [Testing HTTP Basic Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#testing-http-basic-authentication). ;)

Comment: I've seen this example but I don't have access to the annotation for some reason. Am I missing to include something?

Comment: The annotation is included in _spring-security-test_. Just add the dependency _org.springframework.security:spring-security-test_ to your project

Comment: What if you use a jwt token?

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to the previous answer, it's possible to use the following:

```
@Test
public void basicAuth() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
            .perform(get("/")
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic("user", "secret"))
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

since it will generate the same header:

```
Headers = [Content-Type:"...", Authorization:"Basic dXNlcjpzZWNyZXQ="]
```